# How much information should intersection routines return in a path tracer?

Tags: pathtracing, implementation

When designing/coding/"architecting" some geometry-ray intersection routines for a path tracer, there seems to be a spectrum of potential designs, with these two extremes:

1. Return the distance to the intersection only
2. Return the distance to the intersection, the surface normal, the material, the world coordinates, texture coordinates, barycentric coordinates, ...

When we're just looking for the closest hit, the first design is obviously better. But for shading we need additional information, which could be computed quite cheaply in addition to the distance. So, perhaps it's smarter to compute this information for every intersection test? Or we could implement both routines, and use the first to find the first-hit, and then invoke the second one to re-compute the same intersection and all the additional information.

**Is there a "best" design, or is the answer (as always) "It depends"?**

Comment: It depends. For shadow rays you just need a yes or no answer, and you can exit early at any hit (not even the closest). For your normal rays you could have an intersect that returns either the whole data, or just minimal necessary data. The latter is probably better in terms of efficiency, since you can skip computing some things. For instance, for a sphere you could just return the sphere index and the $t$ of the ray, and then compute everything from this. On the other hand, for a triangle you may want to return the uvs also, since you get those from the intersection anyways.